# Cannot upload .mp3 file to wordpress media

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I tried to upload a .mp3 file and wordpress rejected and display message:

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

This happened with some .mp3 file only. I'm using wordpress 4.9.6

Answer (score 2):

you **need to allow them** to be uploaded in your media files.

you can add following code to your themes functions.php

```
function my_mime_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['mp3'] = 'audio/mpeg';
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

there is more information about **adding new mime types in WP** here: https://wpsmackdown.com/add-remove-filetypes-wordpress-media-library/#add-filetypes

And here a list of the **mime_types**: https://feedforall.com/mime-types.htm

Comment: When I checked the code, I found out that the mine_type of the file is >application/octet-stream 
Is it wordpress bug?

Comment: you are right. you can use `application/octet-stream`. it's a official one or also `audio/mpeg` should work. updated my post...